# Send file via UDP with QT

Tags: qt, udp, centos, virtualbox

I am trying send file via UDP from PC to VM - CentOS.

I use: VirtualBox 4.1.2 and I done ping PC to VM an VM to PC and VM to www.google.com and OK

Network VM set as NAT.

The applicatión for transmision UDP is QT and transmion PC to PC and loopback(127.0.0.1) is fine.

any suggestions?

Thanks you very much and excuse me for me English.

Comment: Why don't you use VirtualBox shared folders? Also, if the network is NAT, the VM guest does not have an external address that you can connect from outside (e.g. not the host but other PC)

Comment: Thanks for reply, I am tryning simulate a real scene, where pc remote is a CentOS and the transmition of files is with app QT, why that i don't use shared folders.

Comment: Why UDP? That means replicating a lot of the TCP protocol...

Comment: Why does the project specify that? Seems pretty backwards to me.

Answer (score 0):

[QUdpSocket](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qudpsocket.html) is your friend, if you're bent on UDP.

You need to add a sequence number to each packet though, so using [QTcpSocket](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qtcpsocket.html) would be better.

Comment: Thanks hor reply, I know that sequence number is need, but at moment only send the fragments file in packet of size 8192bytes and any packets arrive to the VM. And bind is correct.